# automatically fire postpaint event

Tags: c#, charts

I have a MS chart and the chart fires a PostPaint event in the end. I want to have a button to have an option to delete the chart.

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();

        chart1.Series.Clear();

        chart1.Legends.Clear();
    }
```

But once I click the button to delete the chart, it would fire the PostPaint event which causes some error. I don't want to fire the event, how does this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

After adding chart1.Visible=false; the problem is gone.